# NSCollectionView dragging - item turns transparent when dragging

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionview

1. Create a collection view with one item
2. Set item's background to blue by calling `NSRectFill` in `drawRect`
3. Add a `NSTextField` to the item
4. Connect `NSCollectionViewItem`s `textField` outlet to your text field
5. Set up basic dragging
6. **Problem: When you drag an item, the blue background is gone and item becomes transparent**

This is what it looks like while dragging:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's behaving this way, but the problem is in connecting `textField` outlet of `NSCollectionViewItem`.

If I leave that outlet unconnected, and create my own outlet (to talk to the text field), then everything works fine.

Comment: Is this the instantaneously found solution to your problem or an addition to the question?

Comment: It's the solution. It was just non-obvious so I wanted to keep track.